# Problem requesting Yahoo OAuth scopes through Roundcube

Tags: yahoo, flurry, scopes, webmail, roundcube

I'm currently using the 1.5 version of Roundcube and trying to configure it to work with the Yahoo mail server. I have created an app and have also allowed the email and profile API permissions from the OpenID.
There is an issue with the scopes and when trying to log in it redirects back to an error page and says: "Please request scope from registered scopes and submit again".
This is the current config for Roundcube:

```
    // Enable OAuth2 by defining a provider. Use 'generic' here
$config['oauth_provider'] = 'yahoo';

// Provider name to be displayed on the login button
$config['oauth_provider_name'] = 'Yahoo';

// Mandatory: OAuth client ID for your Roundcube installation
$config['oauth_client_id'] = '------';

// Mandatory: OAuth client secret
$config['oauth_client_secret'] = '------';

// Mandatory: URI for OAuth user authentication (redirect)
$config['oauth_auth_uri'] = 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth';

// Mandatory: Endpoint for OAuth authentication requests (server-to-server)
$config['oauth_token_uri'] = 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token';
    
// Optional: Endpoint to query user identity if not provided in auth response
//$config['oauth_identity_uri'] = 'null';

// Optional: disable SSL certificate check on HTTP requests to OAuth server
// See http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#verify for possible values
$config['oauth_verify_peer'] = true;

// Mandatory: OAuth scopes to request (space-separated string)
$config['oauth_scope'] = 'openid mail-r mail-w sdct-w';

// Optional: additional query parameters to send with login request (hash array)
$config['oauth_auth_parameters'] = ['nonce' => mt_rand(), 'prompt' => 'consent'];

// Optional: array of field names used to resolve the username within the identity information
$config['oauth_identity_fields'] = null;

// Boolean: automatically redirect to OAuth login when opening Roundcube without a valid session
$config['oauth_login_redirect'] = true;
```

Here are the settings for the app:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKiE5.jpg

The error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVUOm.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjLdq.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6v4c.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGr9d.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu6Ji.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You need to request access to restricted scopes first. Once and if approved you need to create an app and select the mail scope (the email scope is to get access to the users "email" identity, not for access to the mailbox). See https://developer.verizonmedia.com/mail